# How to make different apps to do requests via proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

So, I think there are a lot of answers on this question, but I couldn't find it because of collision, google found only WebRequests with proxy(.

I have several instances of app, it uses Internet and each of instance have more than one(maybe 3) web connectuins. I would like to make each instance to do requests via different proxy. As I know, there are some rules for requests(something similar to windows firewall), but the problem is in different instances.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: So, there is a `Proxy` property for the `WebRequst` class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.proxy?view=net-5.0#System_Net_WebRequest_Proxy) You can just set proxy you want for each request.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to paraphrase, I want to create app that will make other apps do requests via vpn. And not just rules like:
a.exe does reques -> add proxy to request
but different proxy for each process of a.exe. The question is how to do it. I don't want to do requests myself, I want to add proxy to different app's requests.